# Opening url in new tab

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I am trying to open a new tab with javascript.
How to write it so that it would work in chrome, firefox and IE7?
(the pages are on the same domain)

UPD: Let's presume that the user uses the default configuration of IE7...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot control how the browser will handle opening new popups / pages.  This is entirely handled by the browser.  If the user has set their browser up to open new pages/popups in a new window, you cannot force your own page to open in a tab.

Comment: Updated the question (if it really matters)

Comment: It doesn't matter what the configuration of the browser is.  You can't alter it / find out what it is.  So, you won't be able to be 100% certain what a javascript window.open will do (or html target="_blank" - see ZippyV's answer below) - whether it will open a tab or if it will open a new window.

Answer (score 1):

Plain HTML:

```
<a href="newpage.html" target="_blank">click here</a>
```

Javascript:

```
window.open("newpage.html", "_blank");
```

But keep in mind what psynnott said.