# Want to open in New Tab on IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Opening url in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637419/opening-url-in-new-tab)

while i am doing `window.open(),`my page opended in new window,but i want it to be opened in newtab of my browser.
How can do that?

Comment: You cannot control it, it depends on the browser settings.

Comment: you can use anchor tag to open in new tab.Have you tried that?

Comment: @Matrix what will be the target attribute value?

Comment: target will be _new it will work if you use anchor tag :-)

Comment: @Matrix Tried with <a href="Sample.html" target="_new">Your link</a> Not working.

Comment: once check http://tour.mapview.in url and check the links in bottom footer like home,privacy policy... etc., that was developed by us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm 99% sure you can't. There might always be an exception for the Redmond browser, but for the rest in the browser-land you cannot affect how a new window is opened via ECMAscript (which is a *good* thing).

It's a browser setting.

Comment: It *is* possible. Twitter does it. All external links that appear within tweets are opened in a new tab - this works cross-browser (including IE8). Not sure how they do it, have to check.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: would be pretty interresting

Comment: I guess it depends on the OS. I just tried `window.open( 'http://google.com', '_blank' )` - it opens the URL in a new tab in all browsers. (I also tried IE8 mode in IE10)