# window.open opens new window instead of new tab in IE8

Tags: javascript, window

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Want to open in New Tab on IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175634/want-to-open-in-new-tab-on-ie8)

In ie8, window.open() opens new window instead of new tab. Is it a browser behavior? Can we change it? Please give me a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot change. This is a setting in the browser that you cannot change with Javascript - only the user can change it. But this has to be a duplicate, I've heard this so many times

http://www.google.com/?q=javascript%20window.open%20new%20tab