# How can I open a new tab in Google Chrome using the anchor tag accesskey attribute?

Tags: html

Basically, I want the easiest way to hit alt+i and have it open a link in a new tab, not a new window.

Comment: Without control over the browser? You can't. See [Opening url in new tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637419/opening-url-in-new-tab).

Comment: `Ctrl + Enter` should do it. But this better asked on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: <a target="_blank"> opens a new tab in Chrome for me

Answer (score -1):

This should be able to work:

```
window.open("herpaderp.html", "_blank");
```

The first parameter is what you want the link is, the second parameter is open in new tab (or if you changed it, in a new window or something like that)

Comment: The OP is asking how to force opening in a new tab (vs. a new window).